# .htaccess create user friendly url and ridirect to it

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

i tryed to search everywhere for this problem but i didnt found nothing.

I want to make make a url seo friendly so i used this code:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^Homepage index.php [NC,L]
```

Then i want to redirect to it so i tryed to write this code:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://localhost/siti/socialmark/Homepage [R=301,L]
```

The error it's a loop of redirections, can someone help me?

SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH!

Comment: yeah it's infitine loop `Homepage > index.php > Homepage.index.php > ...` so maybe just remove second rule? use PHP to redirect into nice location

Comment: if your only rewriting the url for a search engine, don't bother

Comment: no i want to do it in automatically, because i build entire website based on simple links and now i want to change name of some files... there is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewrite rules don't just make the URL string look different, it actually directs the user to the file at the end of the path even if you don't see it in the address bar. If `Homepage` is a directory containing `index.php`, even if that php file name doesn't appear in the URL, then it's causing a loop because it's directing you to a directory with an `index.php`.

The rule is executed every time that page loads. So, you're redirecting to a page which runs the redirect script, so it runs the rule to redirect again, and that causes the loop. What you want to do is create a condition that says "Don't run this code if the requested page is `http://localhost/siti/socialmark/Homepage`"

Something like this (you may have to adjust it)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/siti/socialmark/Homepage
RewriteRule ^Homepage index.php [NC,L]
```

For more details, see the caveats and example here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Comment: ah, so i cant redirect to a created rule?

Comment: You *can* redirect to the URI with the rule, but the problem is the rule is executed every time the page is requested, so it redirects again. That's why there is a loop. You need a condition that says "Do not run this rule if the correct URI is being requested." I've updated the answer above with an example and link to `.htcaccess RewriteRule` documentation.